# How to ingest files in a docker container from another machine?

Tags: docker, file-transfer, scp

I have a machine on the local network that produces files. It doesn't run Docker because it's a low power single board computer. I have written a Docker container to run on a server to ingest these files, process them, and spit the processed files out.

My issue is in transferring files from the machine into the Docker container for processing. I thought I'd use `scp`, but it doesn't work because Docker containers aren't supposed to have `sshd` running.

I don't see a way to use a Docker Volume, the device producing the files to be processed is separate from the host running Docker. `scp` would be a clean way of doing it because the producer could copy the files over without knowing whether it's processed by a Docker container, a VM, or a real machine.

What are my options at this point? Should I try and do this over (S)FTP or HTTP(S)? Is there a better way?

Comment: Docker does not introduce any overhead that I would consider to be concerning for a machine like you describe: "low-power single board". Docker really just sets up cgroups and namespaces in the linux kernel, and the containerized processes running in your already running kernel. If there is a docker package available for the architecture of this low-power single board computer, you should be able to run docker containers on it fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a good situations for installing sshd in the docker container and then to use scp.

whether you install sshd, sftp, or another protocol based file transfer service into the container, doesn't make too much of a difference, i don't think.

the other options i can see would be having the computer that produces the files send them somewhere that the docker container can reach them. perhaps a shared network folder.

the docker container could mount the network drive directly and pick up the files through the mounted folder.

Answer (score 0):

How about NFS? You could run a second Docker container next to the current one that runs a NFS server and mounts a volume to store data:

```
docker volume create mydata
docker run -d --privileged --restart=always \
-v mydata:/nfs \
-e NFS_EXPORT_DIR_1=/nfs \
-e NFS_EXPORT_DOMAIN_1=\* \
-e NFS_EXPORT_OPTIONS_1=ro,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,fsid=1 \
-p 111:111 -p 111:111/udp \
-p 2049:2049 -p 2049:2049/udp \
-p 32765:32765 -p 32765:32765/udp \
-p 32766:32766 -p 32766:32766/udp \
-p 32767:32767 -p 32767:32767/udp \
fuzzle/docker-nfs-server:latest
```

Then, you ingest the data in your second container by mounting the same volume:

```
docker run -d --name myingester -v mydata:/path/for/processing myingesterimage
```

Now you would just mount the NFS folder (using the Docker host IP) on the data producer at a folder it writes to and the data will be available in the volume.

You can later wrap this up into a `docker-compose.yml` file to deploy them side-by-side (I'll leave that exercise up o you). The image example I found at https://hub.docker.com/r/fuzzle/docker-nfs-server/. But it looks like there are many other NFS server container examples as well.